# How to get a pid of a process?

Tags: c, process, order-of-execution

I want to create a function like this but with priority. For that, I need the pid, but I don't know how to get it. Any idea?

Mine is to use `setpriority (0, pid, value)`, but I need the pid.

```
void cmd_exec(char * tr[]) {
    if (execvp(tr[0], tr)== -1)
        perror("Error");
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `exec*()` functions do never return, but on error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the process-id of the calling process use `getpid()`.

Please find the

- [Linux man-page here.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html)
- [*current* (Issue 7) POSIX documentation here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpid.html#)

Comment: Why not add a link? Did not think it was worth an answer  but get +1 nonetheless

Comment: @EdHeal: Was thinking which dox to link.

Comment: @EdHeal: Moreover I was sure this were a duplicate, but apparently it does not seem so, so I added the answer.

Comment: Usually 6 of one and half a dozen of the other